# Global n-form on Calabi-Yau

Tags: complex-geometry, differential-forms

I am now reading [these](http://www.phys.uu.nl/~vandoren/MRIlectures.pdf) lectures by Stefan Vandoren on complex geometry. Everything is fine in general, hiwever I am confused with how he defines 1-form on a Calabi-Yau 1-fold (or 2-form on CY$_2$).

In particular, if we look at his (5.12), where the 1-form $\Omega$ on CY$_1$ is defined, this can be related to Weierstrass functions by the usual embedding $z\mapsto [1:\wp(z):\wp'(z)]$ of a 2-torus into projective space $CP^2$. Then
\begin{equation}
\Omega=dz=\frac{d\wp}{\wp'(z)}=\frac{dx}{y},
\end{equation}
that is more or less the same as in the paper with $x=z_1/z_0$ and $y=z_2/z_0$.

Then he turns to **Excercise 5.1**, where global properties of the form are invesitgated. Here is my first question: why he defines a 1-form $\Omega_1$ separately instead of just taking transformation of $\Omega$? We go from the patch with $z_0\neq 0$ to $z_1\neq 0$ with $\tilde{x}=z_0/z_1$ and $\tilde{y}=z_2/z_1$. Then we just write
\begin{equation}
\Omega=\frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{\tilde{x}^{-2}d\tilde{x}}{\tilde{x}^{-1}\tilde{y}}=-\frac{d\tilde{x}}{\tilde{x}\tilde{y}}.
\end{equation}
The last term above is precisely his $\Omega_1$. However he starts from another definition for it and then discovers the above identities.

The second question is actually the same but in other notations. In **Exercise 5.2** Vandoren consider a curve in $CP^2$ defined by
$$F(z_0,z_1,z_2)=z_0^n+z_1^n+z_2^n=0$$
with some integer $n$. The question is, why he defines the form to be 
$$\Omega=\frac{dx}{n dy^{n-1}}?$$
As I understand this should be somehow related to the following identities
\begin{equation}
0=df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy=n(x^{n-1}dx+ny^{n-1}dy),
\end{equation}
however I have no idea, what the relation is. Here $F=z_0^3 f(x,y)$ and $x=z_1/z_0,y=z_2/z_0$.

Finally, he again defines the form $\Omega_1$ on the patch $z_1\neq 0$ as
$$\Omega_1=-\frac{d\tilde{x}}{n \tilde{y}^{n-1}},$$
and then derives $n=3$ from the demand that $\Omega_0=\Omega_1$ on intersection. The question is again the same: why couldn't I use instead of his $\Omega_1$, just a coordinate transform of $\Omega_0$ to the patch $z_1\neq 0$? Like this
$$\Omega_0=-\frac{\tilde{x}^{n-3} d\tilde{x}}{n \tilde{y}^{n-1}}.$$

I am a physicist, so it could be that I just do not understand some basic and trivial concept about globally defined differential forms. I would be happy if you could answer my questions. After some search on MathSE I couldn't find any similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer. The point is that the n-form on the n-dimensional hypersurface is said to be a Lerya residue of a (n+1)-form, that is singular on the hypersurface.

If we say that on each patch of the projective plane the n-form should be given by the Lerya residue, then the globality condition gives the power of the polynomial, that defines the surface.